# External API is not reading the parameter I send in the form data

Tags: java, c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to communicate with external api. The API endpoint uses POST method. It uses Form-data to post. I did the implementation of sending the data using MultipartFormDataContent. However, it seems the server is not recognizing any parameter I send. My code is below, I have searched and tried many ways but still got no correct response from the server.

Parameter name: pParty_id

Note: the server respond correctly through PostMan.

```
        public async Task<JsonResult> PostFormAsync<U>(string method, string endpoint, IFormFile file, string pParty_id)
        {
            HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            MultipartFormDataContent multipart = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                {new StringContent(pParty_id),"pParty_id"}
            };

            //foreach (var header in headers)
            //    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);



            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# app");
            //_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

            var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                Headers = {
                    ContentLength = file.Length,
                    ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType)
                 }
            };



            string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


            multipart.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            multipart.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);





            var body = new StringContent(pParty_id);

            multipart.Add(body, "pParty_id");

            body.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("pParty_id");

            switch (method)
            {
                case "POST":
                    response = await _client.PostAsync(
                       endpoint, multipart);
                    break;
            }

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            _client.Dispose();

            return new JsonResult(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<U>(responseString))
            { StatusCode = (int) response.StatusCode };
        }
```

Comment: You explicitly set a Content-Type header field with a customized boundary string. So, where exactly is this customized boundary string being used in the multi-form content, then? I don't see your `boundary` string being used anywhere in your code aside from setting the Content-Type header. You gotta tell the MultipartFormDataContent somehow that it has to use your custom boundary string (and then you probably wouldn't need to "override" the Content-Type header anymore...)

Comment: You mean I have to add it to the MultipartFromDataContent, wiill try this. I have added this header explicitly because the external API always respond that I have not sent the boundary. After adding the boundary, the response changed to 555 with message that argument are not passed (which is the parameter I'm trying to send) From my understanding, the boundary should automatically be set, but in my code, it's not set that way.

Comment: For anyone who's facing the problem. It's because of a small bug in MultipartFormData class. It's producing a boundary with additional double quotes. The solution is either remove those quotes or add boundary manually. Thanks, it worked after registering the boundary